# Win 11 fails to wake screen after sleep

Tags: windows-11, sleep

This is the same issue as several others already asked, but with a different requirement.  Like the other issues, frequently upon waking my PC, the processor will wake but the screen stays black.

Unlike the other issues asked here, I can access my PC via TeamViewer.  So: How can I bring the display back to life without rebooting?

Comment: Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App to update Drivers - BIOS and Power especially.

Comment: @John: Haven't tried that, but won't a driver update require a reboot?

Comment: Yes. Driver updates need restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a keyboard shortcut for that: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec. Look under the "Windows key keyboard shortcuts" section.

| Press this key | To do this |
| --- | --- |
| Windows logo key + Ctrl + Shift + B | Wake PC from blank or black screen. |

Comment: Looks promising.  I'll try that next time it gets into this state.